# VS 2012 can't allocate memory for 10,000,000 size char array

Tags: visual-studio

Today I face a strange problem. When I try to allocate 10M bytes for a char array, I'll receive a stack overflow error when I try to execute the code. Any idea for the problem? Thanks.

Yue

Comment: Show the code. Perhaps you allocated it on the stack, and there's not enough stack space. Perhaps you have a bug in the code that someone sees if they see the same code as you're looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What language are using? Assuming C/C++, and if you allocate your array on the stack, for e.g.

```
char A[10000000];
```

inside a function or block scope, you may be hitting the stack limit of the thread.
Play with this setting in VS
Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - System - Stack Reserve Size

and relink.

It's better to use dynamic allocation for such a size, with

char* A = new char[10000000];

or use malloc() in C.

With these two, you are allocation on the heap area, not on the stack.

Comment: If you get a stack overflow exception, this is the correct answer. The stack on Windows is by default very small (~1M IIRC).